# Appcelerator Hyperloop use TiApplication Class

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop

I am trying to use Hyperloop to use the `isCurrentActivityInForeground` method inside `org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication`

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/TiApplication.java

I have tried the following and some other ways but I am unable to require the class - Any suggestions?

```
var TiApplicationClass = require('org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication');
var TiApplication = new TiApplicationClass;
var isInForeground = TiApplication.isCurrentActivityInForeground();

Ti.API.log("isInForeground");
Ti.API.log(isInForeground);
```

PS. I have asked in the slack channels multiple times but no help

Answer (score 1):

I think *benCoding.Android.Tools* module is what you need: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    var platformTools = require('bencoding.android.tools').createPlatform(),
        wasInForeGround = true;

    setInterval(function() {
        var isInForeground = platformTools.isInForeground();

        if (wasInForeGround !== isInForeground) {
            Ti.App.fireEvent(isInForeground ? 'resumed' : 'paused');

            wasInForeGround = isInForeground;
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Sample code credits to Fokke Zandbergen: http://www.tidev.io/2014/01/28/paused-resumed-events-on-android/

Comment: I am trying to move away from this exactly and use hyperloop as they now have the code needed in the core

See: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25962?focusedCommentId=436920&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-436920

Answer (score 1):

The internal SDK classes are not accessible via Hyperloop so far. But I like the idea! Can you create a ticket the [Appcelerator JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org) so it can be scheduled?

Comment: Hi Hans, I have had a ticket related to this open for a while - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25962?focusedCommentId=436901&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-436901

Let me know if you wanted me to create a new hyperloop related ticket